# A ChannelListen error message appears every time I start Mathematica. How can I stop this?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, channel-framework

Every time I start up Mathematica, I am greeted with the following message:

```
ChannelListen::subx: Failed to subscribe to the channel
mqtts://channelbroker-mqtt.wolframcloud.com:8883/users/aaron.eiben@gmail.com/ChatInvitations.
The channel may not exist or you may not have access to it.
```

It appears three times; then the message is shut off:

```
General::stop: Further output of ChannelListen::subx will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I don't have much experience with / never use Wolfram Cloud, so I don't really care whether or not I'm subscribed to it. I'm just slightly annoyed by these messages every time I start Mathematica. Is there a way to correct the issue causing them or simply turn them off for good?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can run the code **`DeleteChannel[All]`** to delete all the channels you had created. That's the way I did not long ago, and the messages were turned off then.

The problem occurred when I was curious about a blog mentioned it, and I did that by doing so: `文件(file)->新建(new)->聊天会话...`. And from then on, I was the same as you.[image: the position]

Another method for avoiding the message is just use `Off` function, in which you can specify not to show the messages about channels at all.

If you want to delete a specific channel, you can see the document of the function `DeleteChannel`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the problem on my end managed to fix itself, however, because I've not seen that error recently. But if it ever reappears, I'll know what to do!